# "He is very good shape" vs "he has a very good shape"

Tags: sentence-structure

Which sentence sounds more natural to you? I've seen both lots of times:

> 1) He is very good shape.
>
> 2) He has a very good shape.
>
> 3) He is a very good shaped young man.

In my opinion the most should be "good shape**d**", though you will find easily lots of examples on the internet without the ending "ed".

Comment: Side-note: "both" refers to exactly *two* items. You could instead say "I've seen *each* lots of times" (or, preferably, "many times").

Comment: @KyleStrand I'm sure that _both_ in that sentence refers to the two examples in the question: _“He is very good shape” vs “he has a very good shape”_.

Comment: @P.E.Dant But...there's a third example...? They're even numbered!

Comment: @KyleStrand Don't cavil. Be grateful that the OP did not begin his series with the zeroth option.

Comment: @P.E.Dant This is an ELL site. I clarified a point of usage that, from the question, OP appears not to already know. If OP does understand the correct usage of "both", no harm done. Why are you arguing with me?

Comment: @KyleStrand My response was a jocular reference to a previous question regarding ordinals.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Well, sorry I don't spend enough time on the site to understand all the inside references! That only explains your second comment, though, I think.

Comment: @KyleStrand - From much previous experience with the queries posed by A-friend, I've come to understand his thinking. I'm nearly certain that _both_ in his first sentence refers back to the two examples opposed in the title. It's still possible, I guess, that he doesn't understand that _both_ requires exactly two considered together, and if that should be the case, he now has not one but _two_ comments which make that point.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Ah. That also clarifies things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of your three sentences, only the second has any meaning as written in natural English usage.

> He has a very good shape.

This would be taken to mean that his body is well-proportioned. However, it would very seldom be expressed in this way. There is an *idiom* in English which you may be attempting to express:

> He *is in* very good shape.

Without any other context, this is taken to mean "He is in very good physical condition." If context is provided, it could also mean that he is in very good financial, mental, or emotional condition.

Your first sentence is grammatically incorrect. It omits the article:

> He is **a** very good shape.

With the article, the sentence is grammatically correct, but it would elicit puzzlement from a native English-speaking reader or listener.

Your third sentence *could* be analyzed as grammatically correct, but an English speaker would never use "good shaped" here. Instead, the adverbial form of ""good" would modify the participle of the verb "to shape:"

> He is a very **well**-shaped young man.

This would be taken to mean that his body is well-proportioned, as with your second sentence.

Comment: "He is in very good shape" could also refer to his mental condition.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the usage you are looking for is "in shape" meaning fit and having well toned muscles.  To say, "He has a very good shape," would mean his shape (such as round, square, oblong, etc. is very good), which I have never heard used.

> He is in very good shape.
>
> He is a young man in very good shape.

You can use the word "fit" to mean "in shape" and can use it as you have suggested.

> He is very fit.
>
> He is a very fit young man.

Answer (score 3):

"He is *in* good shape" would typically refer to someone who is fit, either mentally or physically.

"He has a very good shape" could refer to, say, a dog which conforms to recommended physical attributes, or some other male with an aesthetically pleasing shape. "He is well-shaped" would be better.

"He is a very good shaped young man" could be read as a "shaped young man" who is "very good". A more usual way of putting that would be "a very well-shaped young man."

Which one is best is down to what you mean.